# Create new columns based on value in rows, from rows with double ID, to single ID rows with double column items

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, which looks like this:

```
df_testretest
   ID   item1  1.2  1.3  1.4  item 2  2.2  2.3  item3 3.2 
1  101    0     NA   NA   NA     1     3    0     1    2
2  101    0     NA   NA   NA     1     3    0     1    2
3  102    1     2    1     6     1     2    0     1    3
4  102    1     3    1     6     1     3    0     1    2
5  103    0     NA   NA   NA     1     3    0     1    3
6  103    1     2    0     5     1     3    0     1    3
7  104    1     1    1     3     1     3    0     0    NA
8  104    1     1    0     4     1     2    0     0    NA
```

I want the data from the questionnaire, so the above dataframe, to be shown per item/column and not per ID/row. So that you have each ID only ones in the rows, and have for each item/sub-item two columns containing the data from the first and second time the participant answered that question

I want the dataframe to look like this:

```
df_testretest
   ID   item1_1 item1_2  1.2_1 1.2_2 1.3_1 1.3_2  1.4_1  1.4_2 item2_1  item2_2  2.2_1 2.2_2 2.3_1 2.3_2 item3_1 item3_2 3.2_1  3.2_2
1  101    0       0       NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     1       1        3     3    0      0        1     1      2     2
2  102    1       1        2     3      1    1       6     6      1       1        2     3    0      0        1     1      3     2
3  103    0       1        NA    2     NA    0      NA     5      1       1        3     3    0      0        1     1      3     3
4  104    1       1        1     1     1     0      3      4      1       1        3     2    0      0        0     0      NA     NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach using `nest` and then `unnest_wider` to unpack the created `tibble`s, followed by another `unnest_wider` to unnest the lists.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  unnest_wider(-ID) %>% 
  unnest_wider(-ID, names_sep="_") %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 4 × 19
     ID item1_1 item1_2 X1.2_1 X1.2_2 X1.3_1 X1.3_2 X1.4_1 X1.4_2 item2_1
  <int>   <int>   <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>   <int>
1   101       0       0     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA       1
2   102       1       1      2      3      1      1      6      6       1
3   103       0       1     NA      2     NA      0     NA      5       1
4   104       1       1      1      1      1      0      3      4       1
# … with 9 more variables: item2_2 <int>, X2.2_1 <int>, X2.2_2 <int>,
#   X2.3_1 <int>, X2.3_2 <int>, item3_1 <int>, item3_2 <int>, X3.2_1 <int>,
#   X3.2_2 <int>
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Note that by default column names should not start with a number.

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 103L, 104L, 
104L), item1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X1.2 = c(NA, 
NA, 2L, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L), X1.3 = c(NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 
1L, 0L), X1.4 = c(NA, NA, 6L, 6L, NA, 5L, 3L, 4L), item2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X2.2 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L), X2.3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), item3 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), X3.2 = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```